# laravel 4 blade template view blank body

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I've started using laravel 3 on a project and part way through decided last night to change to laravel 4 as most of the items I research now seem to reference laravel 4 and it appears the way forward for me. However the differences in between 3 and 4 over the basics is frustrating me not least as I can't find a good reference site with a good reference onn what to change in an upgrade. (I'll keep searching)

Anyway... my problem. I've copied all my controllers and views over to the laravel 4 site. I can get the hello page and a basic html page of my own to display with through a route via a controller. However I can't get a view to render using a template.

I've tested the template on it's own and can get it to render. I needed to remove some helper functions such as to_asset() but for now simply using straightforward markup. This is:

```
views/_layouts/master.blade.php
```

Within this I have created 'placeholders' for my content:

```
@yield('additionalCss')
@yield('shortcuts')
@yield('content')
```

and towards the bottom of the template I have:
    @yield('additionalScripts')

I've created another view using this template...

```
views/articles/index.blade.php

@extends('_layouts.master')

@section('additionalCss')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sangoma-green.css"/>

@stop


@section('shortcuts')
<a class="span2 data-block widget-block" href="/articles/create">
<section>
    <span class="icon-address-book-alt"></span>
    <strong>Add Article</strong>
</section>
</a>

<a class="span2 data-block widget-block" href="#">
<section>
    <span class="icon-flag-alt"></span>
    <strong>Reports</strong>
</section>
</a>
@stop

@section('content')


<div class="row">

<!-- Data block -->
<article class="span12 dark data-block">
    <header>
        ...additional stuff here (removed for post)...
    </header>
    <section>

        <table class="datatable table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="article_table">
... removed content for brevity ...
        </table>

    </section>

</article>


</div>


@stop

@section('additionalScripts')
<!-- jQuery DataTable -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.datatables.min.js">   </script>

@stop
```

When I try to render this view all I get is the following main my browser:

```
<head>
This strangely contains the script markup that's placed at the foot of the page
</head> 
<body></body> which is empty
```

It's as if the view is not referencing the master template.

The views worked correctly in Laravel 3, I've changed the blade mark up (I think) to laravel 4. Can anyone point out the error of my ways please.

Thank you

Comment: I've created a very simple test template and view and was able to render this. However trying to replicate in the view above still doesnt work. I've tweaked my routes as well, changed file locations - it simply refuses to recognise the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

After much headache - the fault was in a rogue laravel 3 url helper that was within a script.

Found in by searching for all instances of {{ and tracked it down

Working now

Comment: Can you elaborate, it sounds like I'm having the same problem.

Comment: naah, he wont elaborate, let others feel what he feels